# iMacross script delete photos one by one

Tags: facebook, imacros

this iMacross script i want to use in facebook.
i want to create iMacross script that will click "Delete this photo" link, wait a second until a dialog box appear and will click "confirm" button.

this is my script so far :

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
TAG POS=1 ATTR=TXT:Delete this photo
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=NAME:confirm
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

but it not works and keep appear error :

```
SyntaxError: wrong format of TAG command, line 6 (Error code: -910)
```

can anyone help?

```
UPDATE
```

The worked code is here for deleting photos in not theater mode. :

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Delete this photo"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:"Confirm"
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Comment: Here is a JS to achieve this https://gist.github.com/stubar/1c98070dad9196b6d3971e09b0eb6e81

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `TAG POS=1 ATTR=TXT:Delete this photo` because the innerHTML (TXT for iMacros) contains Blank spaces to solve this you have 2 options

### #1

replace each blank space with `<SP>` in your `TXT` attribute:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Delete<SP>This<SP>Photo
```

### #2

enclose your `TXT` within double-quotes:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Delete This Photo"
```

Both solutions works, Here's what I have tested

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={ID}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Delete This Photo"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Confirm
```

### UPDATE

To delete the photo in Facebook "theater" mode, we need to open the photo permalink then initiate the "theater" mode using `TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Open Photo Viewer"`

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=162982897217166
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Open Photo Viewer"
WAIT SECONDS= 5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Options
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:"Delete This Photo"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Confirm
```

Further Reading:

- [TAG - iMacros Wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#Parameters)

Comment: thanks @adam azad, i have use your suggestion and it works :)

Comment: this script is only works when we display the photo in a single page just like in screen shot : [link](http://prntscr.com/3ok76b) . not when in theater mode just like this : [link](http://prntscr.com/3ok7fp) .

Comment: my bad not mention it first because i am too excited because this is my first time to use imacros and it work :)

Comment: Updated the answer with a tested solution